# Detect React Router route change inside component to toggle state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-hooks, frontend

I currently have a Navbar component that uses hooks to set a boolean isActive state (the overall app was created using create-react-app). I need to detect route changes to toggle isActive to false in this component, but I'm unable to grasp the bare minimum understanding on how to do so

My component code looks like this:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import Isologo from './../assets/images/isologo.svg';
import HamburgerButton from './../assets/images/button-hamburger.svg';
import './Navbar.css';

const Navbar = () => {
    const [isActive, setActive] = useState(false);

    const handleToggle = () => {
        setActive(!isActive);
    };

    return (
        <div className="navbar-wrapper">
            <header className="navbar">
                <Link to="/">
                    <img className="isologo" alt="Company" src={Isologo} />
                </Link>

                <nav className="navbar-menu">
                    <Link className="navbar-menu-link" to="/sign-up">Start now</Link>
                    <Link className="navbar-menu-link" to="/how-it-works">How it works</Link>
                    <Link className="navbar-menu-link" to="/how-to-upload">How to upload</Link>
                    <Link className="navbar-menu-link" to="/news">News</Link>
                    <Link className="navbar-menu-link" to="/about-us">About us</Link>
                    <Link className="navbar-menu-link" to="/contact-us">Contact us</Link>
                    <Link className="navbar-menu-link" to="/login">Login</Link>
                    <button className="navbar-hamburger-button" onClick={handleToggle}>
                        <img src={HamburgerButton} alt="Menu"/>
                    </button>
                </nav>
            </header>

            <nav className={`navbar-menu-mobile navbar-menu-mobile-drawer ${isActive ? 'is-shown' : ''}`}>
                <Link className="navbar-menu-link navbar-menu-link-mobile" to="/sign-up">Start now</Link>
                <Link className="navbar-menu-link navbar-menu-link-mobile" to="/how-it-works">How it works</Link>
                <Link className="navbar-menu-link navbar-menu-link-mobile" to="/how-to-upload">How to upload</Link>
                <Link className="navbar-menu-link navbar-menu-link-mobile" to="/news">News</Link>
                <Link className="navbar-menu-link navbar-menu-link-mobile" to="/about-us">About us</Link>
                <Link className="navbar-menu-link navbar-menu-link-mobile" to="/contact-us">Contact us</Link>
                <Link className="navbar-menu-link navbar-menu-link-mobile" to="/login">Login</Link>
            </nav>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Navbar;
```

Comment: You can add onClick function to every Link that action is setActive(false). So every Link is click by user it will setActive to false

Answer (score 0):

use useLocation hook (if you are using version 5).

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Link, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom'

const Navbar = () => {

    const [isActive, setActive] = useState(false);
    const location = useLocation()
    const currentLoaction = location.pathname;

    const handleToggle = () => {
        setActive(!isActive);
        console.log('route changed');
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        handleToggle();
    }, [currentLoaction]);

    // your code

};
```

Comment: For clarity here, what he's doing is using the `useEffect` hook in order to detect when the component has loaded, inside the `useEffect` callback function you can check the `isActive` variable to inspect the state of the app.